# Open Button Target In Parent iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the following onclick event assigned to a button, but upon clicking it, i want the openNav function to execute in the parent iFrame, not the child iframe where this code is.

Any ideas?

```
onclick="openNav()"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick="parent.openNav()"`

Should do the trick, provided that the parent document has the same domain as the child iframe document.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)